# Saving Image to default camera folder - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, save

I'm currently finishing a project. But there is one last thing I need and can't figure out how to do.

I'm looking for a way to save images to the default folder (camera roll folder). I was thinking of making a button. So if the user decides to save his image he can tap on the save button.

If it matters, I have 4 imageview on top of each other. Would it be possible to save all those view to one image?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to save an image to the camera roll:

```
-(IBAction)savePhoto{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImageView.image ,nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: I tried that... but doesn't seem to work. Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Which part doesn't work? If you have 4 image views you need four lines with each image view as the variable.

Comment: Ok, it somewhat works. But when I save it, itll save the 4 images separately. It doesn't save it as 1 whole image.

Comment: Basically, what I'm trying to do is to flatten all the images into one. And be able to save it to my album.

Comment: can you take a screenshot of all the images and do it that way?

Comment: I tried actually... I am using landscape view mode. So when I do a screen shot using a code, it'll shoot my image in portrait. Which only shows like 25% of the image... sorry for being complicated. But I thank you for helping me.

Comment: make sure your dimensions are right then you can turn it 90 degrees so it is landscape.

Comment: I manage to do this code. But whenever I tap on the button, itll crash my app. But same time it'll take a picture.

(IBAction)savephoto {
    
    CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
    CGImageRelease(screen);
    
    // You could, e.g., save the captured image to photo album
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,  @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}

Comment: can you post this code in your original post with code tags? It will be easier to see that way.